# Kafka - Delay binding until complex service initialisation has completed

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka, but I have a particular service that has a complex start-up dependency (long-running) that can be rather fragile so would like to delay Kafka (consumer) binding until successful initialization is confirmed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible with Spring Cloud Stream; you can do it by using Spring Kafka directly (e.g. `@KafkaListener`) and set the container factory's `autoStartup` to `false`. Or with Spring Integration Kafka and do the same for the inbound channel adapter.

You could do it with Spring Cloud Stream by loading the `@StreamListener` into a child boot application instead of the main one.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I've opted for the child boot application route which works perfectly.

Comment: Hey, @Oakdale, could you please point out to any documentation that helped you with this problem ? I am having the exact same issue. Thanks.